# mySql - Best way to model price discount table for bulk purchases - Recursion?

Tags: mysql, laravel, e-commerce

Building an eCommerce store, and wish to offer pricing discounts for bulk orders. Each product may have different discount tiers.

e.g. different % discounts dependent on qty ordered.

```
Product  : Quantity Bands[discount]
Product A: 1-10[0%], 11-20[5%], 21-50[15%], 51+[20%]
Product B: 1-5[0%],  6-10[10%], 10+[30%]
Product C: 1-10[0%], 11-20[5%], 21-50[15%], 51+[20%]
```

Bit confused as to how I should model this in a database...

My initial thoughts were to model my discounts table as a self refrencing adjacency list. The product table would have a discount_id to determine which discount band it belonged to.

e.g.

```
discounts table:
id int
name string
discount decimal
parent_id int nullable
```

sample data:

```
id   name    discount child_id
=============================================
1    1-10    0        2
2    11-20   0.05     3
3    21-50   0.15     4
4    51+     0.20     null
=============================================
5    1-5    0         6
6    6-10   0.10      7
7    10+    0.30      null
=============================================
```

products table

```
id int
name string
base_price decimal
discount_id
```

so in the products table, a product can have a discount_id of either 1 or 5. Lets assume discount_id is 5. So to get a table showing prices and discounts for bulk purchases, I recursively loop through the discount_id's starting from 5 until child_id is null?

Am I completely off the mark or is there a better way of modelling this data?

Comment: How about a `Discounts` table that has a record for each discount range per item

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I have updated question with my train of thought...

Comment: How about a ***Discounts*** table with the fields: `id,  QtyRangeLow,  QtyRangeHigh,  Discount,  ProductID`

Comment: By separating the qty range into two separate fields it will be easy to query against.

Comment: Thanks. But then does that not mean that I would have to create a completely new discount strategy for every product in the database?

Comment: Why do you have to have a discount with a child I did not undestand that. I have made some ecommerces and never seen it before. Every one that I made was like `product(fields)` `discounts_ranges(id, minRange, maxRange, discount)` and `productDiscount( idProduct, idDiscount, startDate, endDate )` that way I can set a product with different ranges for different periods of the year

Comment: And in some of then (not ecommerce of course) I could associate a product to a range of discount to a seller, so only some seller could conced specific ranges of discount

Comment: I understand your question now... did not see that the range is for the amount of products. You could use my idea adding a field to represent the quantity of products for the table `discounts_ranges`

Comment: Or another Idea is to forgget about the `child_id` and, instead, separate the ranges so when someone buy something you will see in what range the amount bought fits the discount table.

Answer (score 0):

you need a table with 4 fields

id
product_id
tier
discount

e.g.

```
1 1 1 0
2 1 11 5
3 1 21 15
4 1 51 20
```

and simply join your products table with the order table and the discounts table to figure out the discount to apply for that product